# How to solve problem memory of Opam memory generated by Gringo

Tags: ocaml, opam

I have a problem with OCaml and the Opam package manager. When trying to install any package, Opam makes a call to a process gringo, her quickly consumes 8 gb, so I am obliged to kill the process without completing the installation of the package before the computer starts to crash because the gringo continues to increase the memory consumed.

Can someone give me tips on how to solve the problem?

Comment: I know this used to be a problem... https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=907636

Comment: you can experiment with the `--solver` option to opam, e.g., installing and using mccs solver might help. See `opam --help` for the list of values that this option accepts. Alternatively, reducing the number of compiler variants (with `opam pin ocaml <your-version>`) might reduce the pressure on the solver (as well as removing unused repositories).